# SQL Server 2008 R2 Pivot issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a `Table1` shown here:

```
;WITH Table1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
(164021, 'Balajee', 100, 100, 'YTD'),
(164021, 'Balajee', 200, 100, 'YTD'),
(164021, 'Balajee', 400, 300, 'MTD'),
(164021, 'Balajee', 200, 100, 'MTD')
) as t (EmpID, [Emp Name], GROSS_PAY, NET_PAY, DUR_TYPE)
)
```

This table has column called duration type which can have value as `YTD` or `MTD`. Now I want my table after doing a select using Pivot to look like the one shown in the table below. Can someone help me to do this? I'm very new to this Pivot and need some help.

```
EmpID   Empname Grosspay_ytd    net_pay_ytd Grosspay_mtd    netpay_mtd
------- ------- --------------- ----------- --------------- -----------
164021  Balajee 300             200         600             400
```

Comment: Do you think anyone turns up here asking a question where it's not a high priority to them? It's just rude to assume that your question should be dealt with as a higher priority than anyone else's.

Comment: Thanks for the info Damien The unbeliever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result however part of the problem is that you have the two columns that you want to pivot in two columns.

Since your data to pivot is in two columns there are a few ways that you can get the result.  You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select empid, empname,
  sum(case when dur_type='YTD' then gross_pay else 0 end) gross_pay_ytd,
  sum(case when dur_type='YTD' then net_pay else 0 end) net_pay_ytd,
  sum(case when dur_type='MTD' then gross_pay else 0 end) gross_pay_mtd,
  sum(case when dur_type='MTD' then net_pay else 0 end) net_pay_mtd
from yt
group by empid, empname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576d9/4)

If you want to use the PIVOT function then you can UNPIVOT the data in the `gross_pay` and `net_pay` columns so the data exists in one column and then apply the PIVOT function.  Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you can unpivot the data using CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause:

```
select empid, empname, col+'_'+dur_type as col, value
from yt
cross apply 
(
  values
    ('gross_pay', gross_pay), ('net_pay', net_pay)
) c (col, value)
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576d9/6). This will convert the current data into the result:

```
|  EMPID | EMPNAME |           COL | VALUE |
--------------------------------------------
| 164021 | Balajee | gross_pay_YTD |   100 |
| 164021 | Balajee |   net_pay_YTD |   100 |
| 164021 | Balajee | gross_pay_YTD |   200 |
| 164021 | Balajee |   net_pay_YTD |   100 |
```

As you can see, we know have multiple rows for each employee with a column that contains the 
names of the columns you want in the final pivot result.  When you apply the PIVOT function the code will be:

```
select empid, empname,
  gross_pay_ytd, net_pay_ytd, gross_pay_mtd, net_pay_mtd
from
(
  select empid, empname, col+'_'+dur_type as col, value
  from yt
  cross apply 
  (
    values
      ('gross_pay', gross_pay), ('net_pay', net_pay)
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in (gross_pay_ytd, net_pay_ytd, gross_pay_mtd, net_pay_mtd)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576d9/7). Both this version and the CASE version will give a result:

```
|  EMPID | EMPNAME | GROSS_PAY_YTD | NET_PAY_YTD | GROSS_PAY_MTD | NET_PAY_MTD |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 164021 | Balajee |           300 |         200 |           600 |         400 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql.

```
select empid,empname,sum(case dur_type when dur_type='YTD' then gross_pay else 0 END)as grosspay_ytd,
sum(case when dur_type='MTD' then gross_pay else 0 END) as grosspay_mtd  ,
sum(case when dur_type='YTD' then net_pay else 0 END) as netpay_ytd,
sum(case when dur_type='MTD' then net_pay else 0 END) as netpay_mtd
from employee
group by empid,empname,dur_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have done this by adding case but need to know if we can do it using pivot?

Comment: It is not possible to nest aggregates like this.

Comment: @Pheonix That will not work in SQL server. Nesting aggregates is not allowed it will throw an error message -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/576d9/10

Comment: @bluefeet : tried it in your fiddle but not working. I have done this previously in mysql. so i thought it might have been applicable here as well.